# Add event to my Google Calendar using PHP API

Tags: google-calendar-api

I know that there are many related questions about this and I have been trying this for 2-3 days now without any success.

I have a calendar in my web page where the user can select date and time and then click a button and that entry will be created in my(owner) Google calendar without the need of any authentication. I have already made my Google Calendar as Public. Here is my code:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';
$DEVELOPER_KEY = 'some-key-here';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setDeveloperKey($DEVELOPER_KEY);
$calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();
$event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
  'summary' => 'Google I/O 2015',
  'location' => '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
  'description' => 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
  'start' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2018-05-28T09:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'end' => array(
    'dateTime' => '2018-05-28T17:00:00-07:00',
    'timeZone' => 'America/Los_Angeles',
  ),
  'recurrence' => array(
    'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
  ),
  'attendees' => array(
    array('email' => 'lpage@example.com'),
    array('email' => 'sbrin@example.com'),
  ),
  'reminders' => array(
    'useDefault' => FALSE,
    'overrides' => array(
      array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
      array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
    ),
  ),
));

$calendarId = 'someid@gmail.com';
$event = $calendar->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
printf('Event created: %s\n', $event->htmlLink);
```

When I run this, I get the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on null
```

Where am I making the mistake or have I missed something? Please help.

Comment: Was the answer below correct? Looks like you may have updated the question with the code given in the answer but didn't follow through in confirming the correct answer or solution which is frustrating for others.

Comment: @DylanGlockler it was not the correct solution to my issue, still do you want me to check it as correct since its frustrating for others??

Comment: No, doesn't make sense in that case, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `$calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar_Calendar();` should be `$calendar = new Google_Service_Calendar();`